# How to update the array values from existing based on the condition and again pass same array with updated array element

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We are using for each control to iterate an array based on matchNr count. First time My application is sending all reports call to server together , next time after 10 sec delay again my application sending the same reports calls which are not get completed in first time and so on.

Ex. suppose application is having 10 reports then first time 10 requests goes, then again same request goes by eliminating the completed one (this request count should be less or equal to earlier one)

Note:
Application is having different report count for each users. we can not put fix reports to all users.
Request is same here, only application is adding report name in the body part of the request.

We are trying to simulate chrome behavior with Jmeter during load test.

[Array is having the total report count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ6QJ.png)[image1]

[request is same only parameter is getting change for each request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCdHb.png)[image2]

Answer (score 0):

1. [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) doesn't execute its children "together"
2. We are not telepathic enough to guess how does you "array" look like and how exactly you want to "update" it

If you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of:

```
foo_1=something
foo_2=something else
....
foo_matchNr=number of matches
```

and want to update the variables with some "new" values there are 2 options:

1. [Set Variables Action](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) sampler (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager))
2. Or any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), any of them has `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance providing read/write capabilities for JMeter Variables in current thread's scope.

Comment: Hi Dmitri , Thank you for response. I have added image for reference, my array is initially having 10 reports, now suppose server has completed 2 reports Now I need to send only 8 from 10, how we can achieve it? Here we are not getting pending report count from server. We are trying to do this via bean shell processor.